# Create a RSS feed:// protocol handler with Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, rss

I want to create an application which can handle RSS feeds. On the net I found a couple of tutorials explaining how to create a RSS reader, but most of them explain how to parse the feed *given* the URL. I don't need this part.

What I would like to do is only handling the feed:// protocol, i.e. when for example on Safari I open a feed using an application, one of the RSS reader application Safari proposes would be my application, just like Vienna or NetNewsWire.

It is possible to do this via the code, right? Because I just installed Vienna, and when I choose in Safari to open a feed using an application, Vienna opens up automatically.

Comment: Yes it's possible.  Are you asking how to do it?  Here's a recent question with a great code snippet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927252/has-there-been-a-change-to-the-way-mac-osx-mavericks-handles-cfbundleurlname-cu

Comment: Yes that was what I was asking! Do you want to post an answer?